# UI freeze when switching windows' focus on Ubuntu (20.04) with Gnome

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gui, freeze, window

When I boot it works correctly. After a day or so of usage this problem appears: when switching focus of a window (either from one window to another or from window to desktop or vice versa) windows freeze, i.e. I can't interact with the window (and animations inside this window stop), for a couple of seconds (and it gets worse if I try to do this rapidly). Even when switching focus to the desktop, the selector (click&drag rectangular selection for desktop icons) is very laggy. Leaving the focus on one window seems to work okayish - I think I can work normally when the focus remains on a specific window. I've primarily observed this with Chrome windows but native applications like Files seem to be "affected" as well. I just issued `killall -3 gnome-shell` and the problem seems to go away.

I didn't observe this issue until recently (maybe after some ubuntu update, not sure) even with days of uptime.

I don't think there is lack of hardware resources, at least judging from the htop/monitor - neither CPU nor RAM seem to be anywhere near starvation. I haven't checked disk usage when the problem appears but I highly doubt that's the issue (I'm using a fast nvme drive). My point is I don't know where to look for a problem.

I tried searching for similar issue and there are plenty of issues with UI freezes/lags but I couldn't find something like my case.

1. Can someone help me / point me how to troubleshoot this. What could be possible "bottlenecks" or issues, what logs/things to look for, etc., or
2. If this is a known issue, please point me to a resource.

Comment: on gnome you can restart the shell with `Alt+F2` then enter `r` and hit `enter` -- that might be better than `killall` -- this is just anecdotal but i believe to remember a few stories where chrome was iffy

Comment: is ubuntu 20.04 installed on laptop ? if yes check which windowing system are you using in Settings->About. If it's Wayland then Log Out and choose X11 and also disable in Gnome-Tweaks -> General -> Show Animations

Comment: @kannzzmm2 No, it's a desktop.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 20.04 window reveal and focus works correct if: Gnome-Tweaks -> General -> Show Animations (true) and Alt+F2 and r

Comment: @evgenitsvetanov did you find a solition? I'm having the same symptoms, although keyboard and mouse movements usually work, only "clicking" does not.

Comment: I haven't found a solution and to be honest I was mostly looking for how to troubleshoot such an issue.